# Removing certain characters from model input in Html.EditorFor (Razor / ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorformodel

**model.Question2AResponse** and **model.Question2AResponse** are two fields that are of type decimal. I want it to be so the user can enter commas into the **Html.EditorFor** boxes and have them display, but the model not actually take the value of the comma. So display the comma the user types in, but not actually save the value to the model. Is that possible?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Questions</legend>
        <div id="content">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question2A.QuestionText)
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question2AResponse)
            <br />
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question2B.QuestionText)
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Question2BResponse)
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Previous" />
            <input type="submit" name="Command" value="Next" />
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: is comma valid inside a decimal value in your current culture ?

Comment: Adding a comma to the decimal value results in the value being 0. I think that's just how it works in C#.

Comment: You still did not answer my question

Comment: lol. It is not valid. The model value is being passed off to another data source, so it cannot have commas. The point is to be able to remove the comma before this happens (if the user inputted any commas).

Comment: You need to handle it in the controller action. Not the view

Comment: If you are going to allow user to enter comma, you need to make the type of your view model property to string and then in action method try to parse it back to a decimal value and use that for your saving your entity model

Comment: @fhogberg when the controller is called the value of the decimal has already become 0 from the comma being added to the decimal value. So that can't work.

Comment: @Shyju That sounds right, thanks

Comment: As @Shyju suggested. Make the controller accept strings.

Comment: @tonyleMill This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35093882/40521) might help you to get started