# asp.net mvc validation annotation for dollar currency

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am validation for `Html.TextBoxFor`. Here is my code on the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new {@class = "form-control", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Amount) })
```

This code takes the double value from the database like 5000.00 and displays on the UI as $5,000.00. However when the user hits the submit button, a validation error is displayed that

> The value '$5,000.00' is not valid for Amount.

My validation annotation on the Model is

```
[Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid dollar amount")]
```

To get it to submit, I had to retype as 5000.00. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550361/how-do-i-properly-format-a-readonly-textboxfor-value-as-currency

Answer (score 2):

When you do the `value = string.Format("{0:C}", Model.Amount)` in the htmlAttributes, razor will execute the C# code and return the value,`"$125.67"`, (Assuming the value of your `Amount` property is  `125.67M`) which is a string. So the markup generated by your view will be

```
<input value="$125.67" class="form-control" id="Amount" name="Amount" type="text">
```

Now since `$125.67` is not not a valide decimal value, but a string. it cannot map the value of this textbox to the `Amount` property of your view model which is of type decimal/doube.

What you can do is, create a new property in your view model of type string to store this formatted string value and when user submits the form, try to parse it back to a decimal variable and use it.

So add a new property to your view model

```
public class CreateOrderVm
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string AmountFormatted { set;get;}  // New property
  public decimal Amount  { set;get;}
}
```

And in your view, which is strongly typed to CreateOrderVm

```
@model CreateOrderVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmountFormatted, new { @class = "form-control",
                                Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.Amount) })

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your HttpPost action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateOrderVm model)
{
    decimal amountVal;

    if (Decimal.TryParse(vm.AmountFormatted, NumberStyles.Currency,
                                             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out amountVal))
    {
        vm.Amount = amountVal;
    }
    else
    {
       //add a Model state error and return the model to view,
    }

    //vm.Amount has the correct decimal value now. Use it to save
    // to do  :Return something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own Binder object to handle this.  First create this object:

```
public class DoubleModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
  public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
    ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;
    try
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
        actualValue = Convert.ToDouble(valueResult.AttemptedValue.Replace("$", ""), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
      modelState.Errors.Add(e);
    }

    if (bindingContext.ModelState.ContainsKey(bindingContext.ModelName))
      bindingContext.ModelState[bindingContext.ModelName] = modelState;
    else
      bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
    return actualValue;
  }
}
```

Then in your Global.asax.cs file in the Application_Start function, add this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(double?), new DoubleModelBinder());
```