# Client-side validation of US currency

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 web application and I need to accept user input of US currency. Some valid inputs might be:

```
100
$100.21
$ 1,234
$1,234.56
```

Invalid inputs might be:

```
10,12
1o0.21
```

My (simplified) model looks like:

```
public class Claim {
  [DisplayName("$ Amount)]
  [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
  [Required]
  [Range(0.0, 200000.0)]
  public decimal? DollarAmount { get; set; }
}
```

My cshtml markup looks like:

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DollarAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
  <div class="col-md-9">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DollarAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DollarAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
```

I used this advice [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35093392/asp-net-mvc-validation-annotation-for-dollar-currency) to build a binder that converts user input to a decimal, but client-side validation won't let the user enter a dollar-sign or commas. What do I need to do to allow the user to enter valid currency values, but warns her if she enters an invalid value? I'd prefer to do as much validation on the client-side as possible.

Comment: Cant you add a `[DisplayFormat]`?  For example: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{$###,###.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`

Comment: It didn't seem to work. When it went to display the Claim, it threw System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format' when parsing  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DollarAmount). I also tried [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)], which didn't throw, but didn't let me enter a $ in the input field, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pool pro's answer was a great help in solving my problem but I couldn't get his input tag pattern to display a message. It worked in JSFiddles, but not in my Asp.Net view template. So, I did the pattern validation and message update in javascript. I also used a different regex. For completeness, I'm posting my solution here:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DollarAmount, new { @id = "DollarAmount" })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DollarAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
<div class="col-md-9">
    <input id="DollarSave" type="text" name="DollarSave" class="form-control text-box single-line">
    <p id="BadDollarSave" class="text-danger"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#DollarSave').on('blur', function () {
        validateDollarSave();
    });

    function validateMoney(inputId) { 
        var errorMsg = '';
        var currency = $('#DollarSave').val();
        var good = currency.match(/^(\$|\$ )?[0-9]{1,3}(?:(,[0-9]{3})*|([0-9]{3})*)(?:(\.|\.[0-9]{2}))?$/);
        if (!good) {
            errorMsg = "$ Amount must be US currency";
        } else {
            var num = currency.replace(/[, $]/g, "");
            $('#DollarAmount').val(num);
        }
        document.getElementById('BadDollarSave').innerHTML = errorMsg;
    };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Might want to look at https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#currency-module. Helps allot with this kind of stuff.  As for your Question to be able to use the Dollar Symbol you would not be able to store this Value as a decimal format in the database, only as a string.

There are a few things you can do, Use bootstrap to place a Dollar symbol in front of your TextBox using `input-group-addon`. Not sure if it will work properly as i see you have set Margin-bottom on your Textbox, telling me you might not be using bootstrap form tags above.

You may want to look into [AutoNumeric](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric) jQuery plugin, It's well-maintained and they've basically "thought of everything" I could want for currency.

```
// View

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DollarAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DollarAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control margin-bottom" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DollarAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>


// Class

public class Claim {
  [DisplayName("$ Amount")]
  [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
   // {0:C} Will show as currency {0:N} to show Numbers
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true))] 
  [Required]
  [Range(0.0, 200000.0)]
  public decimal? DollarAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Another option is to have a hidden field with javascript that will duplicate the field from a string to decimal and that can be the one you submit like below.

```
// MODEL
public class Claim {
  [DisplayName("$ Amount")]
  [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
  [Required]
  [Range(0.0, 200000.0)]
  public decimal? DollarAmount { get; set; }
}


// View

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DollarAmount, new { @id = "DollarAmount" })

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DollarAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9 input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input id="DollarSave" type="text" name="DollarSave" pattern="^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$" title="You must enter in proper currency">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DollarAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#DollarSave').change(function(){ 
  var sourceField = $("#DollarSave").val(); //source field key
  $("#DollarAmount").val(sourceField); //destination field key
  $("#DollarAmount").change(); //destination field key
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! While I couldn't get your solution to work (the pattern wouldn't fire, probably due to the view template I was using), it pointed me in the right direction, I used pieces of your solution,  and I have the problem solved! I'll accept your answer and post my solution below.

Comment: I am sorry, In MVC 5 it is easier to place the JS script in a file and call it with render script at bottom of the page otherwise it calls the script before javascript.

Comment: I was actually doing that. I didn't show it to keep the question and answer simple.